# How can I sanitize Erlang input?

Tags: erlang, io, sanitization

I was playing around with the erlang shell today and noticed that I could do command injections, something like the following:

```
io:get_chars("Cmd> ", 3).
Cmd> Dud List=[3,4,5]. io:get_line("I just took over your shell!").
```

Is there a way to sanitize the get_chars function's input so this isn't possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you aren't really doing command injections.
`io:get_chars("Cmd> ", 3).` simply does it's job: read 3 characters from the input stream.
everything entered after these is processed by the erlang shell as part of the normal read-eval-print loop.